# Air app for Playbook: Performance difference between FlexSDK 4.5 and Blackberry SDK?

Tags: blackberry, air

I have a swf that was compiled using Flex SDK 4.5

I then package the swf into a bar using the Blackberry Air SDK 1.1.1

When I install a release version of the app on the playbook (OS 1.06), the graphic performance is bad, appr. 2/3 of the performance on the iPad1. The app is a game which relies heavily on graphics.beginBitmapFill().  is set to gpu.

I wondered if there would be any performance difference if the swf would be compiled directly using the Blackberry Air SDK. (really doing it would mean some efforts for other parties, so I am asking before). I am not using any native UI elements, so this would be solely for the reason of better performance. Will the Blackberry SDK treat my code any differently when compiling the swf?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Actually using Flex instead of native SDK is not a good idea if:

1)Your app using a lot of animations , in that case the app designed in Flex is not as good as for the same app designed in native SDK.

2) if its a game then forget using Flex better use native SDK.
3)every phone has different aspect ration , screen size, pixel density etc. so u may face some problems on run time.

Comment: Thank you for you answer! The problem is solved after updating the Playbook OS (I was advised to do so in the blackberry dev forum). So I am still using the ordinary Flex SDK. But too bad we still cant have Air3 on the Playbook :/ Have a nice day!

EDIT: yes, it is a game, but since we are targeting to many platforms we have our own logic to detect screen size, aspect ratio etc. and display the scenes accordingly. So this is not a problem.